# What kind of animations are there in Android? Precise classification

Tags: android, animation

I am messed with classification and distinguish of Android animation types. Android official site says there are 3 types of animation: property, view and drawable. But I have discovered, that there is 4th kind: transition animation, with its transition framework. And for example, if we apply animation to Activity screen or Fragment screen, what kind of above animation it is?

Answer (score 2):

Some useful animations

Following i am giving xml code to perform lot of useful animations. Try to assign different values to xml attributes to see change in animations.

1. Fade In
2. Fade Out
3. Cross Fading
4. Blink
5. Zoom In
6. Zoom Out
7. Rotate
8. Move
9. Slide Up
10. Slide Down
11. Bounce
12. Sequential Animation
13. Together Animation

You can show full expiation here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: Ooh, thank you for your answer! But I am interested in a more common Description of animation kinds. Because I have messed, for example, which is Property Animation and which is View Animation. :)